# Adicionar conteúdo em elemento que conter o "elemento" data-layer na tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<ul class="dropdown-list-autocomplete" id="Layer_1abc" data-layer="Layer_1"></ul>
```

E esse JS:

```
function AtivaAutoComplete(id_mapa, regiao, path_map){

$("ul#dropdown-list-autocomplete[data-layer='"+id_mapa+"']").append('<li>'+regiao+'</li>');

}
```

O que quero fazer é: A tag que conter o elemento `data-layer` com o valor `Layer_1` ou `Layer_2`, etc.. Receberá o valor de `append()`, mas isso não está funcionando. Só funciona quando eu digo qual **#ID** é.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu elemento possui uma **classe** `dropdown-list-autocomplete` e um **id** `Layer_1abc`, e, no seu código, você está procurando pelo **id** `dropdown-list-autocomplete`.

Se você mudar seu seletor para:

```
$("ul.dropdown-list-autocomplete[data-layer='Layer_1']")
```

ou

```
$("ul#Layer_1abc[data-layer='Layer_1']")
```

ele irá encontrar seu objeto.

Código funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/rqLqza9b/

Comment: Obrigado amigo, falta de atenção mesmo rsrs.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli de nada! Boa sorte com o projeto!